# How do I migrate circles from a Google Apps for Business account to a regular Google Plus account

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus, google-takeout

I have a Google Apps for Business account and a regular Google account. I want to transfer my G+ circles from the Apps account to the regular one.

I have attempted this by logging in to the Apps account and using the [takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout) service for migrating circles. When I am on the first page of the process (*Step 1. Choose Destination*), I enter the email address of my regular account into the *Destination Account* field and as soon as I click in to the *Sign in to this account* button, my browser signs me *out* of every Google account that I had been signed in to, no matter which ones I had been signed in to.

I've tried this with every possible configuration. It seems that the Apps account signs everything out (itself most importantly) as some sort of security measure and thus the whole process is stopped. I would really like to move my circles to the other account. How do I get around this issue?